# Using co-ordinates to draw a line

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list of X,Y co-ordinates and I'd like to visualize these on my program. What function would be best to use? I will hard code in a base set of co-ordinates before expanding to read from a text file. I am able to do all this, but all the functions I have seen on the net are only for 2 x,y co-ordinates, my X,Y co-ordinates require around 10 or so plots. If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What UI library are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Comment: Winforms for now, but I might change to WPF as I like it better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use GDI+ and the `Graphics` object. Basically, you'll override the `OnPaint` method of any `Control`, and draw your points somewhat like this:

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;

Point p1 = new Point(20, 20);
Point p2 = new Point(50, 50);

g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, p1, p2);
g.FillEllipse(Pens.Red, p1.X - 2, p1.Y - 2, 4, 4);
g.FillEllipse(Pens.Red, p2.X - 2, p2.Y - 2, 4, 4);
```

... and so on. That particular example draws a line between coordinates (20, 20) and (50, 50) with a 4-pixel-diameter circle at each extremity.

Comment: Thank you so much! Am I able to attach that to a button click?

Comment: @user1251019: Yes! But you shouldn't. Instead, just keep some kind of state or data variable in your class, and call `this.Invalidate();` to tell the graphics to draw.

Comment: Oh yes, should of thought of that myself! Silly me! Thank you so much!